# Angular ng-repeat not showing data from Meteor.call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to get data to a view in an ng-repeat.

Here's the controller

```
class dashboardFaqsCtrl {
  constructor($scope, $reactive) {
    'ngInject';

    $reactive(this).attach($scope);

    this.faqs = [];

    Meteor.call('getFaqs', function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(res);
        this.faqs = [res.data.faq];
        console.log(this.faqs);
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Here's the method

```
import Future from 'fibers/future';

Meteor.methods({
  getFaqs: function( ) {
    // Create our future instance.
    var future = new Future();

    HTTP.get( 'http://example.com/faq', {}, function( error, response ) {
      if ( error ) {
        future.return( error );
      } else {
        future.return( response );
      }
    });

    return future.wait();
  }
});
```

The view:

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in dashboardFaqs.faqs">
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The view doesn't repeat the ng-repeat.

How can I make angulars ng-repeat update or show the data returned from this HTTP call from the server side?

Thanks!

**ANSWER**

Was able to figure it out thanks to the comments and answers, here's what I changed:

```
class dashboardFaqsCtrl {
  constructor($scope, $reactive) {
    'ngInject';

    $reactive(this).attach($scope);

    this.faqs = [];

    Meteor.call('getFaqs', function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(res);
        this.faqs = res.data.faq;
        $scope.dashboardFaqs.faqs = this.faqs;
        console.log(this.faqs);
        $scope.$apply();
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: you need to tell angular to update the scope, check out $apply

Comment: @johhan, I think you don't need $scope, as you are using controllerAs syntax. If you use controllerAs syntax, you just want to use *this* instead of $scope. Check out this page in the turorial: http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/3-way-data-binding. Of course, as aw04 says, you need $apply, to tell angular to update the bindings. Also, I think you need *dashboardFaqs* in 'this', because you are using it in your ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass data in $scope

```
class dashboardFaqsCtrl {
  constructor($scope, $reactive) {
    'ngInject';

    $reactive(this).attach($scope);

    this.faqs = [];

    Meteor.call('getFaqs', function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(res);

        this.faqs = [res.data.faq];
        $scope.dashboardFaqs = this.faqs;
        console.log(this.faqs);
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Try It!!!